# How to pass json data from one page to another in angular 2 application

Tags: angular, json-api

My page 1 is a non angular page. 
My requirement:
On clicking the search button of this page, an API will be hit that will fetch data from a JSON API. For making this hit , I have to pass my search query to JSON API. The results of the webservice hit has to be dispalyed on next page(results page) which will be rendered using angular 2.
So no ajax is made here. How do my Angular 2 page receive the JSON data results?How is redirection from server to angular app page and processing of json data on this page achieved?

If I make an http ajax hit for results from the angular app page only, how do I pass my search query in json form to the api since search query was on first(non angular) page?

search.jsp-The non angular page. ActionURL takes me to results page where my search query with city will be set in a request attribute server side in SEARCH_QUERY_ATTRIBUTE and result.jsp page will be returned.

```
<form name="search" action="<%=actionURL%>">
<select name="city">
<option val="DEL">Delhi</option>
<option val="BOM">Mumbai</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Result.jsp-The angular page. Here I bootstrap my angular app and have my main selector.

```
<script>
        System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>

  <my-app>
  </my-app>
```

main.ts

```
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [ HTTP_PROVIDERS ]);
```

app.ts

```
import { Component,  OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Inject} from '@angular/core';

import { SearchService } from './search.service';


@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
   templateUrl: "app/search.html",
   providers:[ SearchService ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  { 
    constructor(@Inject(SearchService)  private searchService: SearchService) { }
    searchObj : string;

        getSearchService() {
 //     this.searchService.getSearch().then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
          this.searchService.getSearch().then(searchObj => this.searchObj = searchObj);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getSearchService();
    }
}
```

search.service.ts - This will make an ajax request to fetch results json. In request, I need to pass my SEARCH_QUERY_ATTRIBUTE as json string to the webservice.

```
/// <reference path="../node_modules/typings/index.d.ts" />

import { Injectable }    from '@angular/core';
import {Headers, Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import {Inject,forwardRef} from '@angular/core';

//import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
//import {Observer} from 'rxjs/Observer';
//import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'; 
//import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';


@Injectable()
export class SearchService {
    private _baseUrl = 'restwebsvc/searchresult';

    http: Http;


    constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => Http)) http: Http) { this.http = http;}

    getSearch() {
         let headers = new Headers({'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
         return this.http.post(this._baseUrl, **SEARCH_QUERY_ATTRIBUTE**, {headers: headers})
               .toPromise()
               .then(response => response.json())
               .catch(this.handleError);


    }

     private handleError(error: any) {
    console.error('An error occurred', error);
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
  }
}
```

I am making an ajax hit from result page to get the results for the search.
So how do I access my SEARCH_QUERY_ATTRIBUTE in search.service.ts to pass as json in http request.

Or is there a way that when I submit my search.jsp I make a hit for results on form submission(instead of ajax on the result page) and then set my results json in a variable(request), return my result page and then access my result json on app.ts.

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: And please provide the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish.

Comment: basically I have an object set using request.setAttribute("SEARCH_QUERY"). How do I pass it to my ts file so that it can be passed to the ajax made using angular 2 http request?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you are talking about. Please show some code.

Comment: I have edited my question with code

Comment: So what you referring to as "page" is just a component. The link I posted in my first comment should provide all you need.